# CSS3 Multiple Background Vertically Aligned

Tags: css

With CSS3 you can use multiple background images.

Let's say I have a DIV container with dimensions: `div {width:100px; height:200px;}`.

I have 4 `100/50px` background images and I want to align these vertically so that the entire DIV is filled with these 4 backgrounds top to bottom.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have multiple images in a background in css3 http://caniuse.com/#feat=multibackgrounds

http://jsfiddle.net/79TyM/

```
#container {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background: 
       url(http://placekitten.com/100/100) left top no-repeat,  
       url(http://placekitten.com/g/100/100) right top no-repeat,   
       url(http://placekitten.com/g/100/100) left bottom no-repeat,     
       url(http://placekitten.com/100/100) right bottom no-repeat; 
}
```

OP wanted the backgrounds stacked, not in a square.  Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/79TyM/1/

```
#container {
    width:100px;
    height:400px;
    background: 
       url(http://placekitten.com/100/100) left top no-repeat,  
       url(http://placekitten.com/g/100/100) left 100px no-repeat,   
       url(http://placekitten.com/g/100/100) left 200px no-repeat,     
       url(http://placekitten.com/100/100) left 300px no-repeat; 
}
```

Comment: This is close, but I want all images under each other. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible using the `background: url(...)` property. A good explanation can be found [here](http://css-tricks.com/stacking-order-of-multiple-backgrounds/).

Basically this is the syntax:

```css
...
background: 
    url(number.png) 600px 10px no-repeat,  /* On top,    like z-index: 4; */
    url(thingy.png) 10px 10px no-repeat,   /*            like z-index: 3; */
    url(Paper-4.png);                      /* On bottom, like z-index: 1; */
...
```

Comment: I've seen that example before but what I am trying to figure out is how to get all background under each other without further repeating.

Comment: the no-repeat should take care of that.